# laravel-8, multidimensional table of array validation required not working

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation

blade file:

```
 @foreach ($zones as $zone)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="zone_id[]" value="{{ $zone->id }}">
                                        {{ $zone->name }}
                                    </td>
                                    @foreach ($productweights as $pw)
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="costs[{{ $zone->id }}][]"
                                                class="form-control" placeholder="costing"
                                                value="{{ ship_costing($zone->id, $pw->id) }}">
                                            @error('costs')
                                                <span class="text-danger"> {{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror

                                          
                                        </td>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

here costing is the multidimensional array which to be varified. there are solution with dot notation but here it's not working. ` public function rules()
{

```
    return [
        'costs' => ['required']

    ];
}


public function messages()
{
    return [

        'costs.required' => 'required arr',

    ];
}`
```

although in form-file required not working.
i have put `costs.* and costs.*.*` still it's not working. when i put numeric in request it gives error msg but it doesn't take any numeric value.
at this time i need some expert help

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to validate a multi-dimensional array.
Your input name is `costs` which is an array.
I've written a similar tests using your codes and here how it works on my case.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'costs' => 'array|required',         // the field must be an array
        'costs.*.*' => 'required|numeric',   // each element must be a number
    ];
}
```

I hope this code will work same on your case.
Give it a try and let me know the result.

Comment: still it escape validation rules

Comment: Can you show me your updated code?

Comment: i just copy paste yours in my code.

Comment: ` public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // 'costs' => 'required',

            'costs' => 'array|required',         // the field must be an array
            'costs.*.*' => 'required|numeric',   // each element must be a number

        ];
    }


    public function messages()
    {
        return [

            'costs.required' => 'Must be numeric',
            'costs.arary' => 'Must be arr',
            'costs.*.*.required' => 'numeric',
            'costs.*.*.numeric' => 'numeric'
        ];
    }`